# how to populate text field with a selection from a JComboBox in java GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java GUI I'm having trouble filling text field
using a JComboBox data from a text file 
text files has multiple rooms with the following format

accountNumber <> customerName <> balance

when an account number is selected from the combo for the 
right name and balance need to populate on the text field
so far I have a class called AccountUtility which reads the data
from the text file I am using an ArrayList to populate the combo box 
and a hashmap to map all names and balances
so far I am only able to populate the combo box 
I'm having problems filling in the text file 
any help and suggestions are really appreciated

```
 //class that reads text file//////
 public class AccountUtility {
    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] number;
    String columns[], accountNumber, customerName,balance;
    int size;


public AccountUtility(){


    BufferedReader in = null;
    try{    // assume products.txt already exists
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("accounts.txt"));
    String line = in.readLine();
    while(line != null)  {
    columns = line.split("<>");
    accountNumber = columns[0];
    customerName = columns[1];
    balance = columns[2];

    test.add(accountNumber);
    map.put(customerName, balance);


                    line = in.readLine();
            }
            in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
            System.out.println(ioe);
    }
} 
 public ArrayList<String> getAccountNumbers( ){
     return test;
}
public HashMap<String, String> getMap(){
    return map;
}




//method on main class that populates JComboBox
    public AccountApp() {

        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Populate JComboBox
        AccountUtility gc = new AccountUtility();
        for( String one : gc.getAccountNumbers()){ 
        accountNumberComboBox.addItem(one);
        }
    }
```

This is what the GUI looks so far

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjgEj.png)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. You want to fill the text boxes of customer name and balance on selection of a account number in the drop down menu right?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Your code requires a little bit of remodeling. Let's walk through the code changes to be made.

1. There is no need for an extra `ArrayList` to to hold account
   numbers. Your `HashMap` can handle that. Make **account number** as
   a `key` and the combination of `customerName` and `balance` as
   value(This only holds good if your app has unique account numbers).
2. Avoid writing **business logic** inside your constructor. If
   anything goes wrong, your object will not be created and this leads
   to many other issues. Instead, create a method say,
   `fetchAccountDetailsFromFile(String filePath)` which will read the
   file and create the resultant `HashMap` of account details.

Now, let's jump into the code.
Let's assume that your `accounts.txt` file contains these following sample records:

> JO123 <> John <> 12,000
>
> SM456 <> Smith <> 15,000
>
> Mi789 <> Mike <> 18,000
>
> Ha121 <> Harvey <> 40,000
>
> Lo321 <> Louis <> 38,000

Now, your `AccountUtility` class should be looking like this:

```
 public class AccountUtility {

        private Map<String, String> fetchAccountDetailsFromFile(String filePath){
            //Create Map
            Map<String, String> accountDetails = new HashMap<>();

            try(BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)))){
                String eachLine = "";
                while((eachLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null){
                    //Split at '<>'
                    String[] details = eachLine.split("<>");
                    //if each line does not have 3 fields, continue.
                    if(details.length < 3){
                        continue;
                    }

                    //get details of each field.
                    String accountNumber = details[0];
                    String customerName = details[1];
                    String balance = details[2];

                    /*
                     * Create name and balance combined String
                     * Ex: nameBalPair = Smith|15,000 
                     */
                    String nameBalPair = customerName + "|" + balance;

                    //add into Map
                    accountDetails.put(accountNumber, nameBalPair);
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //return Map
            return accountDetails;
        }
//Yet to add accountApp() method
    }
```

Now, you can call this `fetchAccountDetailsFromFile(String filePath)` method in your `accountApp()` method to get the generated `HashMap`.

And in order to set the `customerName` and `balance` to the text field, you need to define an `ActionListener` to the `JComboBox`.

So, you can write your `accountApp()` method like this:

```
public void accountAPP(){
        //Initialize all your JFrames, JPanels etc.

        //call the method to get generated Map.
        Map<String, String> accDetails = fetchAccountDetailsFromFile(ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH);

        //Combo Box
        JComboBox<String> accountNumbers = new JComboBox<>();

        //Text Field for customerName
        JTextField customerName = new JTextField(20);

        //Text Field for balance
        JTextField balance = new JTextField(20);

        /*
         * Iterate through your keySet from the accDetails map
         * and add each key (acct. numbers) to the Combo box.
         */



        for(String accountNumber : accDetails.keySet()){
            accountNumbers.addItem(accountNumber);
        }

       /*
        * Add action listener for the combo box which will set the
        * text fields on account number selection.
        * (This is Java 7 style of adding an ActionListener)
        */
        accountNumbers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String selectedAccountNo = (String)accountNumbers.getSelectedItem();
                String custNameAndBal = accDetails.get(selectedAccountNo);

                // split the value obtained at '|' to get name and balance.
                String[] nameBalDetails = custNameAndBal.split("\\|");
                customerName.setText(nameBalDetails[0]);
                balance.setText(nameBalDetails[1]);

            }
        });

        /*
         * Add your components to JFrame and follow with your other business logic
         */ 

    }
```

This should help you in setting customer name and balance on selection of account number.

If you are using Java 8, you can also write the `actionListener`  as:

```
accountNumbers.addActionListener(l -> {

                String selectedAccountNo = (String)accountNumbers.getSelectedItem();
                String custNameAndBal = accDetails.get(selectedAccountNo);
                String[] nameBalDetails = custNameAndBal.split("\\|");
                customerName.setText(nameBalDetails[0]);
                balance.setText(nameBalDetails[1]);
        });
```

I hope this helps you in your learning.

Comment: Under accountAPP when using                                                         Map<String, String> accDetails = fetchAccountDetailsFromFile(ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH);                                is there a way to directly call account.txt file ? instead of calling the file path

Comment: Yes, `ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH` is nothing but a `String` that represents the path to `accounts.txt` file. The function call can be also made like this: `Map<String, String> accDetails = fetchAccountDetailsFromFile("C:/docs/accounts.txt")`